# AVR8 Real Time Scheduler, Serial Communication

Tags: c, real-time, avr, job-scheduling, serial-communication

I am currently programming an ATmega32u4. I have implemented serial communication which is implemented using a build in interrupt that executes every time there is a byte received on the Rx pin. The byte on the Rx pin is placed in a one byte buffer which is replaced when another byte is received on the Rx pin. This is a built in library in atmel.

```
ISR(USART1_RX_vect, ISR_BLOCK)
{
   RingBuffer_Insert(&usart_rx_buffer,UDR1);
}
```

My code executes an interrupt when a byte is received on the Rx pin. When a byte is receives this byte is entered into my ring buffer uart_rx_buffer where it is later decoded.

If an interrupt is being executed and this causes the one byte buffer to be replaced before the UART interrupt can be executed, this byte is lost.

The result of this is that other interrupts cannot take longer than the baud rate to execute otherwise serial bytes are lost.Is there any way to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve this problem would be to use the attribute *ISR_NOBLOCK* in all interrupts that take longer than the baud rate, causing the interrupt enable flag to be activated by the compiler as early as possible within the ISR and allowing the *USART1_RX_vect* to be executed inside other interrupts. However, "care should be taken to avoid stack overflows, or to avoid infinitely entering the ISR for those cases where the AVR hardware does not clear the respective interrupt flag before entering the ISR".

I've experienced this same problem and so far this was the best solution I could think of. *I didn't use it nor tested it*, though.

**Edit**: keep in mind that all other interrupts could also be executed inside interrupts declared with the attribute *ISR_NOBLOCK*, not just the interrupt you want. So you would basically allow all interrupts to be nested inside all interrupts, except *USART1_RX_vect* (and those declared with *ISR_BLOCK*). This is the main problem with this solution (besides the stack overflow problem).

Answer (score 1):

> The result of this is that other interrupts cannot take longer than the baud rate to execute otherwise serial bytes are lost. Is there any way to avoid this problem?

All your observations are correct. While allowing nested interrupts like suggested in Nuno's answer could work, it is normally something you would/should want to avoid. Allowing nested interrupts everywhere makes code petty unpredictable.

I would first try to optimize the execution time of the interrupts that are blocking your UART receive ISR. Take a look at the interrupt priorities. If several interrupts are pending, they will be executed according to this priority. This can result in "starvation" of lower level interrupts, if there is "always" a higher level interrupt pending.

What is your baud rate? Even at 115200 bit/s you can execute about 700 instructions (assuming 8MHz) per byte received. ISRs should be as short as possible. If there is one single ISR that is taking long and you can't optimize it for what reason whatsoever, you could consider just allowing nested interrupts in this single ISR (this is only feasible if the execution is not critical).

If you use a high baud rate, consider reducing it. 9600 baud is often enough, but may require asynchronous sending to prevent blocking code.

Comment: if the execution of that long interrupt is not critical than the task should not be done in interrupt context. in that case the ISR should only set some flag that is processed in the main loop.